# rails 4 and thoughtbot/clearance - adding fields to the user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, clearance

I am a relative newbie so would really appreciate any assistance.

I'm using Rails 4.2, with the Clearance gem for authentication. I'm hoping someone could describe the best practise for over-riding the controllers to include custom attributes on the sign_up form.

I've read a lot of suggestions with varied advice, many of which are from previous versions of rails that do not use strong_parameters.

If anyone could provide a brief breakdown of the methods I need to be over-riding (user_params/user_from_params/etc) I would be most grateful. I can get things functioning by defining a new 'new' method that just includes @user = User.new, and the a new 'user_params' method using .permit, but I'm concerned about the default code I'm bypassing in user_from_params.

Any advice on best practise here would be fantastic!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working when I have time on updating the docs for Clearance, but right now the simplest thing to do is to inspect the [Clearance users controller](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/master/app/controllers/clearance/users_controller.rb) to see the various methods that can be overridden.

The default implementation of `user_from_params` is a bit odd now because Clearance 1.x still supports Rails 3.x, so it was written for a time when we used `attr_accessible` rather than strong parameters.

I'd probably do something like:

```
def user_params
  # Use strong params to do what you need
end

def user_from_params
  User.new(user_params)
end
```

You may need to massage `user_params` a bit so that whatever you do there is still valid for the `new` action, as `user_from_params` is still used there. I've opened an [issue in Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/542) to see if we can improve that aspect before 2.0.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response, much appreciated!!

Comment: You can do it by only overriding one method (see below!)

Answer (score 6):

First, extend `Clearance::UsersController` and override `#user_params` to permit the new attribute(s):

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController

  private

  def user_params
    params[:user].permit(:email, :password, :your_custom_attribute)
  end
end
```

Then, update your routes file to use your new controller:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users, controller: :users, only: :create
```

Comment: Thanks! This works just as you'd expect. The only thing I'd add is making `user_params` a `private` method.

Comment: @psparrow doesn't this cause issues in your `new` action? Pretty sure you will need to also override either `new` or `user_from_params`...

Comment: You need to route to `#new` as well, otherwise you will get an **ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError** . The line should be: `resources :users, controller: :users, only: [:new, :create]`